# Finding out the Python used to install the current package?

Tags: python, package, pip, setuptools, distutils

Is there a way to programmatically find which Python version was used to install the current package?

If you have a package called `mypackage` and it has in its `setup.py` something like:

```
scripts = ["myscript.py"]
```

suppose install the package with `easy_install` or `pip` using a particular Python version, Python 2.x:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.x setup.py install
```

Then in `myscript.py`, how can you find out that it was `/usr/local/bin/python2.x` that was used to install `mypackage` from `myscript.py` as opposed to some other Python version available on the system? I'd like to know the full path and not just the version info because I want to use `/usr/local/bin/python2.x` in my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sys.executable`.

> A string giving the absolute path of the executable binary for the
>   Python interpreter, on systems where this makes sense. If Python is
>   unable to retrieve the real path to its executable, sys.executable
>   will be an empty string or None.

Comment: will that always retrieve the python used to install, as opposed to the python that's first in the environment variable (like bash's `PATH` variable)?

Comment: AFAIK, It's the absolute path to the interpreter used to run the script that access `sys.executable`, doesn't use `PATH`. The description used there is the one in the [`sys` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `sys.version` or `sys.version_info`.

Comment: That tells me the version but I need to know the path where it is on the system so that I can invoke it from `myscript.py`